# Duplicate and Mirror GeneralPath

Tags: java, 2d, java-2d

Is there a way to duplicate a generalpath, mirror it, and move it?

I was creating a cartoon character, and I realized her left side of the hair, body is the same as the right side.

For example:

[image]

I have done the left part of her hair and body and the code is very long.

So to finish the character faster, I thought maybe there is a way of duplicating the code, flip it horizontally and move it to the right position.

I have this sample code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    GeneralPath body, mirror;

    body = new GeneralPath();
    mirror = new GeneralPath();

    body.moveTo(205.5,97);
    body.lineTo(207,132);
    body.quadTo(193,105, 197,80);
    body.curveTo(188,98, 156,127, 159,167);
    body.quadTo(163,174, 166,184);
    body.curveTo(173,196, 193,210, 213,208);
    body.curveTo(247,208, 267,196, 274,184);

    g2d.setPaint(new Color(255,251,223));
    g2d.fill(body);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
    g2d.draw(body);

    //mirror = duplicate(body)
    //flip(mirror)
    //mirror.moveTo(x,y)
    //..something like that
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a transformation. See [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) tutorial for some examples.

Here is an example based on the original code in the question:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(600, 300);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponents(g);
                        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

                        try {
                            GeneralPath body, mirror;

                            body = new GeneralPath();
                            mirror = new GeneralPath();

                            body.moveTo(205.5, 97);
                            body.lineTo(207, 132);
                            body.quadTo(193, 105, 197, 80);
                            body.curveTo(188, 98, 156, 127, 159, 167);
                            body.quadTo(163, 174, 166, 184);
                            body.curveTo(173, 196, 193, 210, 213, 208);
                            body.curveTo(247, 208, 267, 196, 274, 184);

                            g2d.setPaint(new Color(255, 251, 223));
                            g2d.fill(body);
                            g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
                            g2d.draw(body);

                            AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform
                                    .getScaleInstance(-1, 1);
                            tx.translate(-274 * 2, 0);
                            g2d.transform(tx);

                            g2d.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);
                            g2d.fill(body);
                            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
                            g2d.draw(body);
                        } finally {
                            g2d.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                };
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Mirror", 
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]